# What caused the unexpected outline below?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

What caused the unexpected outline below?

```
   \documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-1)(5,5)
        \pstGeonode(0,0){O}(4;0){A}(4;60){B}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{A}{M}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{B}{N}
        %\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!50]
        {
            \psarc[origin={N}](N){2}{(B)}{(O)}
            \psarcn[origin={M}](M){2}{(O)}{(A)}
            \psarc[origin={O}](O){4}{(A)}{(B)}      
        }
    \end{pspicture}


    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-1)(5,5)
        \pstGeonode(0,0){O}(4;0){A}(4;60){B}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{A}{M}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{B}{N}
        \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!50]
        {
            \psarc[origin={N}](N){2}{(B)}{(O)}
            \psarcn[origin={M}](M){2}{(O)}{(A)}
            \psarc[origin={O}](O){4}{(A)}{(B)}      
        }
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

Expected outline but I want it with a color.

[image]

Unexpected result

[image]

Comment: I have not used PSTricks for several weeks, I almost forgot it. :-)

Comment: So you were using `tikz` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-1)(5,5)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){O}(4;0){A}(4;60){B}
    \pstMiddleAB{O}{A}{M}
    \pstMiddleAB{O}{B}{N}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!50]
    {
        \psarcAB(N)(B)(O)
        \psarcnAB(M)(O)(A)
        \psarcAB(O)(A)(B)      
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside `\pscustom` are no optional arguments of single graphic objects valid. Everything must be defined by the optional argument of `\pscustom` itself, the reason why you cannot have different origins.

Answer (score 2):

Use pst-eucl syntax for arcs.

```
\documentclass[12pt, x11names, pdf]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-1)(5,5)
        \pstGeonode(0,0){O}(4;0){A}(4;60){B}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{A}{M}
        \pstMiddleAB{O}{B}{N}
        \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=LightSteelBlue1!50,linecolor =Coral1,arrows = -c]
        {
            \pstArcOAB{O}{A}{B}
            \pstArcOAB{N}{B}{O}
            \pstArcnOAB{M}{O}{A}
        }
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For angles are also different inputs possible: values, PS code, nodes, ...

Comment: @Herbert: I didn't know that — it isn't mentioned in the basic documentation, if I'm not mistaken. Anyway, I'll remove that sentence from my solution.

Comment: run `texdoc pstricks` page 147

Comment: @Herbert: thanks for the information. I must say that when I have to check some detail, I used to look into `pst-user.pdf`, which is more recent – but actually far less complete.

Comment: exactly the same on page 105